# How do I share an "internationalization" project among multiple .NET projects?

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I have three different projects that need to share an "Globalization" project containing the strings/resources.

- ASP.Net Web project
- ASP.Net MVC project
- WCF service project

How to use globalization project as a common project in all above projects?